# Set varwidth to column width with multicol package

Tags: boxes, multicol, varwidth

I'm using two columns with the multicol package. I have some text that I put inside a `\colorbox` as below, and I use `varwidth` to make it include line breaks.

If the lines are short, the box width expands just enough to include the text. Is there a way to make the box have the width of the column?

Below is the command I use for the box.

```
\newcommand{\songbox}[1]{
\colorbox{light-gray}{
\begin{varwidth}{\textwidth}
\textit{#1}
\end{varwidth}}}
```

I'm new to latex, so simplicity would be appreciated.

[image: Sample]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *don't* want to use `varwidth`, if your purpose is that the grey box covers the whole column width.

The purpose of `varwidth` is to make the enclosing box as wide as necessary to encompass the material inside.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,multicol}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{.85}

\newsavebox{\songboxbox}
\newenvironment{songbox}
 {\begin{lrbox}{\songboxbox}\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\columnwidth-2\fboxsep}\itshape}
 {\end{minipage}\end{lrbox}%
  \par\medskip\noindent
  \colorbox{light-gray}{\usebox{\songboxbox}}%
  \par\medskip}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
Some text some text some text some text
some text some text some text some text
some text some text some text some text

\begin{songbox}
In this long line the box goes all the way
to the right margin. And it wraps nicely.
\end{songbox}

Some text some text some text some text
some text some text some text some text
some text some text some text some text

\begin{songbox}
This line ends here.

Another line.
\end{songbox}

Now we fill the columns. \lipsum[1-10]

\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

The environment form seems better, in my opinion.

[image]